# Why the MUI datagrid width shrinks when flexed positioned with pagination component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Recently, I have been trying to incorporate MUI datagrid to my project.

I am trying to display my data in the datagrid table and use a custom pagination. In order to do so I disabled the datagrid footer and added a separate pagination component provided by mui.

Here is my code:

```
return(
         <div style={{ height: 400, width: "80%", border: "1px solid black", margin: "auto", display: "flex", "flex-direction": "column", alignItems: "center", gap: "10px" }}>
            <DataGrid
                getRowId={(row) => row.date}
                rows={errorLog}
                columns={columns}
                hideFooter={true}
                initialState={{
                    pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 10 } },
                }}
            />
            <Pagination count={10} />
        </div>
);
```

But now I see that the width of the datagrid has shrinked

Here is the image
[image]

In the documentation, it has been mentioned that

```
By default, the Data Grid has no intrinsic dimensions. Instead, it takes up the space given by its parent
```

In my case, the parent is the `div` component, but as one can see in the image the datagrid is not taking up the whole width.

Please guide me on what I am missing here.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing.